# R: How do I make a one-variable scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have five categories and the first category has 100x more records than the fifth one.

I want to show a comparison between categories, but bar charts wouldn't make sense.

I also don't want to take the log, since I want to communicate the absolute values.

[image]

I have a category, x, called number of records. The idea is that y is an arbitrary axis and x is the categorical records. It's like a bar chart with dots instead of bars or a histogram with dots.

Is this something I can do with ggplot?

Comment: Will you be able to provide a sample data and code? Otherwise people cannot help you.

Comment: How many columns of dots do you want to have per category? Or do you just want random jitter on the x-coord for each dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `geom_jitter()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(records = c(rep("a",1000),rep("b",500),rep("c",100),rep("d",10)))%>%
  mutate(y = 0)

data%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = records,y = y))+
  geom_jitter()
```

Reference: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_jitter.html

Comment: +1. nice workaround. if you add this to ggplot object: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL, labels = NULL)` y axis would show as an arbitrary axis.